# Wordpress Universal Header Footer Overriding Site Navigation & Footer

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, themes

On Azure hosted Wordpress site I have to use a Universal Header/Footer (UHF) which when activated overrides the sites header/footer.

I require the sites original Navigation and added Footer code to run.

These are the README.md instructions:

### Theme integration

Once UHF has been configured, minor changes need to be made within your site's theme(s):

Begin by wrapping the theme's current header in a `Microsoft\UHF\is_active()` conditional statement. This helper method will determine if UHF is configured and active for the current site. Meanwhile, your existing code will be in the `else` portion of the conditional, enabling your site's current functionality to persist should UHF ever be deactivated.

**Example:**

```
<?php if ( function_exists( '\Microsoft\UHF\is_active' ) && \Microsoft\UHF\is_active() ) : ?>

    <?php \Microsoft\UHF\get_header(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <!-- Your original header -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please note that the UHF header should be the first thing under the `<body>` element, but it does **not** replace your existing `<head>` element!

The footer replacement will be similar:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( '\Microsoft\UHF\is_active' ) && \Microsoft\UHF\is_active() ) : ?>

    <?php \Microsoft\UHF\get_footer(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <!-- Your original footer -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's your question? And `'\Microsoft\UHF\is_active'` is your custom function? As i cannot find the relative resources about "Microsoft Universal Header/Footer"

Comment: I need the MSFT UHF to work without disabling the Site's original header & footer.

Comment: Seems that you want to customize your header and footer when you activate the UHF. If I understand right, could you please try to use code like this:<?php if ( function_exists( '\Microsoft\UHF\is_active' ) && \Microsoft\UHF\is_active() ) :
\Microsoft\UHF\get_header(); 
else : 
get_header();
endif;
?>

Answer (score 2):

The provided code samples show how to *replace* the header and footer with UHF's (when the feature is activated), but if you need the UHF header and/or footer *and* your original header/footer, you can adjust the conditional statement, e.g.:

```
<?php if ( function_exists( '\Microsoft\UHF\is_active' ) && \Microsoft\UHF\is_active() ) : ?>

    <?php \Microsoft\UHF\get_header(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- put your header here, outside the conditional -->
```

**Source:** I wrote the plugin.